# How would a camshaft start moving during a cold start?

Tags: cold-start, camshaft, crankshaft, technology

I want to know how would a camshaft ( and valves by association ) start moving on a cold start up? What gets them running and moving. Are there something they connect to to get them going?

Comment: For mass-produced engines, there is nothing special going on with the camshaft(s) on cold start - they will always be driven by a timing chain or belt off the crank, regardless of whether the engine runs hot or cold.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Crank shaft has a pulley or a sprocket at the front end, which turns a cam shaft/shafts through a cam chain or cam belt (timing belt). 1 turn of a cam shaft = 2 turns of a crank shaft. At the other end of a crank shaft is a flywheel which being turned by a starter motor for a start. Crank shaft is the first shaft in the whole engine which turns everything else.
[image]

Comment: That is an unusual crank configuration.

Comment: yea, just noticed :D Just a random pic from google. Looks like a 1-2-3-4, never seen that before!

Comment: @user15938 - If this answers your question, please feel free to check it as the answer :o)